# Filter only specific type of request

Tags: java, servlet-filters

Recently I'm developing an app in which we need to filter just specific type of requests. For example only GET or POST.  It is easy to check type in code and simply forward to the next filter in `doFilter` method, but I wonder if there is some way to define it in the web.xml file? For example something like:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>SomeFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.src.SomeFilter</filter-class>
   <filter-type>POST</filter-type>   <<<<< this
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>SomeFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** there is [no such configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1015060) in deployment descriptor, you can use code to determine request type

```
httpRequest.getMethod();
```

Comment: That what I'm actually doing. Thx ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such thing to configure in web.xml.But you can use `getMethod()` method of `ServletRequest` object in Your filter class and design your logic there in doFilter() method.